# Intl.NumberFormat return wrong result on Safari 15

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I test this code on some browser and found the difference:

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(123456.789))
```

- Chrome and Edge : $123,456.79.
- Safari 14 and lower: $123,456.79
- Safari 15: **US$123,456.79**

Why on Safari 15 we have a difference result ? And how we change it same Chrome and Edge ? Thanks you

Comment: Seems like it's a bug in Safari 15.

Comment: What's your OS locale? On my en-US macOs I get "$123,456.79" in Safari 15.3

Comment: @Kaiido Idk how to set OS locale but in my PC with English language  in Language and Region setting I got US$123,456.79. When I try change language to Viet Nam result is 123,456.79 US$, 
And when I try on another Mac PC with English language I got $123,456.79. I think this is a bug on Mac Os. 
Have another method for format number currency instead Intl.NumberFormat ?